# What kind of account does the Calendar support?

Tags: calendar, accounts

I cant add events to the Calendar, nor the default nor aCalendar because I need to have an online account to sync them. 
In Settings/Accounts I have the option to add a Corporate Account (Exchange), Facebook and Yahoo. Facebook and Yahoo do not work, Exchange looks like the right option but I dont have Exchange.
I am using Android 4.1 and it doesn't have the Google applications installed.

Is there another alternative like using a webcal or a local calendar?

Comment: many calendar apps support Google account.

Comment: Doesn't it need to have the Google apis installed? Maybe I did something wrong but I have installed aCalendar and it ask me to connect to Google Calendar through the Android Accounts (Those under the Sync & Account in Settings), I cannot connect directly.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the [Business Calender](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=netgenius.bizcal) app, or one of the offline Calendar apps.